# Stud wall bracing

Tags: framing

[image]

I need to remove a steel brace in the wall between my bedroom and the garage. I'm building a closet in the garage for the bedroom.  I'm opening the wall to install mirrored sliding doors.  There is a metal brace running down into the area I will need as the opening to the closet.  Can I remove the brace and should I replace it. That would require a steeper angle to the floor plate.

Comment: Oh I probably didn't do it right.  I tried again let me know if it worked.  lol

Answer (score 1):

That can be answered only after a careful examination of the framing in that wall, and of lateral loading and determining whether other braces also exist within the wall. Best case you can remove that brace and never worry about it. Worst case the building could collapse.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the area that you live in the building structure may contain bracing such as this to help mitigate problems that can occur when earth quakes happen.

So really make sure you check things out to determine if local building codes require that brace to be there. You could be in for future liability problems if you just remove it.

Comment: +1 Looks like shear strap to me, but those are usually cross braced.